# nestJs + gql route conflict/override

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, gql

Hello guys I have an issue with conflicts/overrides inside my nestJS application.

So what is the issue:

I Have Resolver A

```js
@Resolver('ResolverA')
export class SomePageResolver {
  constructor(private readonly someService: someService) {
  }

  @Query(() => someType)
  theThingThatMessesUpStuff(
    @Args('params') params: HttpParamsInput,
    @Context(TokenPipe) authorization: string,
    ): Observable<ActionSetsPageType> {
    return this.someService.doSomething(params, authorization)
  }
}
```

And a resolver B

```js
@Resolver('ResolverB')
export class SomePageResolver{
  constructor(private readonly someService: someService) {
  }

  @Query(() => someOtherType)
  theThingThatMessesUpStuff(
    @Args('params') params: HttpParamsInput,
    @Context(TokenPipe) authorization: string,
    ): Observable<ActionSetsPageType> {
    return this.someService.doSomethingElse(params, authorization)
  }
}
```

Respectively `Resolver A` is part of `Module A` and `Resolver B` is part of `Module B`.

Depending on the build I have, there is a chance that both `Module A` and `Module B` are imported in a single module (single parent module), which leads to the overwriting issue.
The essence of the issue is that when both modules are part of the build, if the client makes a query for `theThingThatMessesUpStuff` it will make a query using the module that is imported last

```js
// some code
@Module({
  imports: [
    // some imports
    ModuleB,
    ModuleA
  ]
})
// some more code
```

If the example configuration from above is used, whenever the client tries to query `theThingThatMessesUpStuff` field, the query will be resolved by the implementation inside `ModuleA`, where for some of the features (inside the front end related to this build) the client will expect the implementation inside `ModuleB`

And now back to the main question, is there a way without involving too many people, to create a validation that will guarantee, that only unique GQL queries exist in the scope of nestJS application.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have figured out two solutions:

1. Somehow implement across all teams and people part of the project a naming convention, in the form of some kind of prefix, which will do the trick as long every team member knows about it and is vigilant.
2. Create a decorator function and decorate all queries

```js
const registered = {};

export const uniqueKey = () => {
  return function(_target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    if (registered[propertyKey]) {
      console.error(`${propertyKey} already in used`);
      throw new Error(`Resolver name already in use`);
    } else {
      registered[propertyKey] = true;
    }
  };
};
```

And this thing will be used as so

```js
@Resolver('ResolverA')
export class SomePageResolver {
  constructor(private readonly someService: someService) {
  }

  @uniqueKey()
  @Query(() => someType)
  theThingThatMessesUpStuff(
    @Args('params') params: HttpParamsInput,
    @Context(TokenPipe) authorization: string,
    ): Observable<ActionSetsPageType> {
    return this.someService.doSomething(params, authorization)
  }
}
```

With this solution once again the developers should be vigilant and use the decorator everywhere, also this decorator should be applied trough the whole code-base, for consistency (which is quite unpleasant task).